# run an exe using c# and read its output

Tags: c#

I want to run the proxifier.exe using by using C#.

I tried this code below but it doesn't do anything, except running the proxifier program. It doesn't give me any output.

```
private string runProxifier()
{
    string strOutput = null;
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Proxifier.exe";
        pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pProcess.Start();
        strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return strOutput;
}
```

I call it after the `InitializeComponent();` but it doesn't show anything, even my wpf form doesn't show. There is also no error thrown.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You've got the output. But are you sure you display it as output in your program? Are you even using the function?

Comment: yes im using the function,

Comment: @imadammy just output `strOutput` and you're golden